# Парсинг данных из nvidia-smi

Tags: python, парсер, nvidia

Задача состоит в том, чтобы парсить текущее энергопотребление для каждой карточки из nvidia-smi,

Сделал следующий скрипт

```
import subprocess
def get_gpu_info():
    sp = subprocess.Popen(['nvidia-smi', '-q'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        
    inf_p1 = []
    inf_p2 = []
    two_gpu_flag = False
    out_str = sp.communicate()
    out_list = out_str[0].decode("utf-8").split("\n")
    new_line = []
    for i in range(len(out_list)):
        if out_list[i] == "":
            new_line.append(i)
    split_arr = []
    for i in range(len(new_line)-1):
        if new_line[i] - new_line[i+1] < -5:
            split_arr.append(new_line[i])
            split_arr.append(new_line[i+1])
    out_list_1 = []
    out_list_2 = []
    if len(split_arr) > 2:
            two_gpu_flag = True
    for i in range(1000):
        sp = subprocess.Popen(['nvidia-smi', '-q'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        
        out_str = sp.communicate()
        out_list = out_str[0].decode("utf-8").split("\n")
       
        if two_gpu_flag:
            two_gpu_flag = True
            out_list_1 = out_list[split_arr[0]:split_arr[1]]
            out_list_2 = out_list[split_arr[2]:split_arr[3]]


            out_dict_gpu1 = {}
            out_dict_gpu2 = {}

            for item in out_list_1:
                try:
                    key, val = item.split(':')
                    key, val = key.strip(), val.strip()
                    out_dict_gpu1[key] = val
                except:
                    pass
            for item in out_list_2:
                try:
                    key, val = item.split(':')
                    key, val = key.strip(), val.strip()
                    out_dict_gpu2[key] = val
                except:
                    pass

            device_id_gpu1 = out_dict_gpu1['Minor Number']
            power_gpu1 = float(out_dict_gpu1[ 'Power Draw'].split(" ")[0])
            inf_p1.append(power_gpu1)
            device_id_gpu2 = out_dict_gpu2['Minor Number']
            power_gpu2 = float(out_dict_gpu2[ 'Power Draw'].split(" ")[0])
            
            inf_p2.append(power_gpu2)

        else:
            out_dict_gpu1 = {}
            for item in out_list:
                try:
                    key, val = item.split(':')
                    key, val = key.strip(), val.strip()
                    out_dict_gpu1[key] = val
                except:
                    pass

            device_id_gpu1 = out_dict_gpu1['Minor Number']
            power_gpu1 = float(out_dict_gpu1[ 'Power Draw'].split(" ")[0])
            inf_p1.append(power_gpu1)
    if two_gpu_flag:
        power_gpu1 = sum(inf_p1) / len(inf_p1)
        power_gpu2 = sum(inf_p2) / len(inf_p2)
        return {device_id_gpu1 : power_gpu1 , device_id_gpu2 : power_gpu2}
    else:
        power_gpu1 = sum(inf_p1) / len(inf_p1)
        return {device_id_gpu1 : power_gpu1 }

print(get_gpu_info())
```

Он хоть и работает, но строка `out_str = sp.communicate()` отрабатывает очень долго

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь удобный и более быстрый способ парсинга данных через python из nvidia-smi

Comment: Лучше возьмите XML, парсить его нормальным парсером (например [lxml](https://lxml.de/)) будет в миллион раз проще `nvidia-smi -x -q`

Comment: И да, как вы определили, что долго отрабатывает именно communicate? Я вижу у вас цикл `for i in range(1000):` — может, вы сами искусственно замедлили работу программы в тысячу раз? В чём смысл этого цикла и почему именно тысяча?

Comment: @andreymal для измерения средней скорости вычисления на 1000 прогонах, но в данный момент это не так важно
скорость работы communicate определил простым ручным тестом

Comment: Вычисления чего? И это очень даже важно, потому что вы запускаете тысячу процессов, а это само по себе небыстро. В чём смысл?

Comment: @andreymal как мне кажется цикл не запускает количество процессов, равное количеству нужных итераций )
Вычисления скорости парсинга нужных данных на 1000 последовательных прогонов

Comment: @andreymal сейчас попробую через xml, спасибо

Comment: Вы измеряете не скорость парсинга, а скорость запуска и работы процесса nvidia-smi, который отрабатывает примерно за 60 миллисекунд (на моём компьютере). Вы никак не сможете его ускорить, кроме как попросив компанию NVIDIA заняться оптимизацией этой программы. Но я всё ещё не понимаю, в чём смысл? Обычно никому не нужно запускать nvidia-smi чаще одного раза в секунду, даже специализированные программы мониторинга обычно ограничиваются одним разом в секунду.

Comment: @andreymal ну суть в том, что мне нужна именно быстрая скорость парсинга - получения словаря {номер_девайса : потребляемая_мощность } , частью чего является и запуск процесса nvidia-smi

Comment: Так как узким местом является именно работа процесса nvidia-smi — вы никак не сможете ускорить это без участия компании NVIDIA. А компания NVIDIA скорее всего вас вежливо пошлёт, потому что вы хотите странного

Comment: Хотя можно немного ускорить, ограничив количество собираемых процессом данных `nvidia-smi -q -d POWER` — так у меня отрабатывает за 11 миллисекунд (однако в таком выводе отсутствует `Minor Number` и я не нашёл откуда его взять)

Comment: @andreymal , через xml и правда работает быстрее,  скорость одного прогона уменьшилась с ~0.8c до ~0.4c, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring

import time

def get_gpu_info(*args, **kwargs):
    p = Popen(["nvidia-smi", "-q", "-x"], stdout=PIPE)
    outs, errors = p.communicate()
    xml = fromstring(outs)
    datas = []
    driver_version = xml.findall("driver_version")[0].text
    cuda_version = xml.findall("cuda_version")[0].text

    for gpu_id, gpu in enumerate(xml.getiterator("gpu")):
        gpu_data = {}

        minor_number = gpu.findall("minor_number")[0].text
        power_R = gpu.findall("power_readings")[0]
        power_draw = power_R.findall("power_draw")[0].text


        gpu_data["minor_number"] = minor_number
        gpu_data["power"] = power_draw
        datas.append(gpu_data)
    return datas 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = time.time()
    get_gpu_info()
    print(time.time() - c )
```